# Proxy can see https headers?

Tags: security, https, proxy

I know that using HTTPS prevents a man-in-the-middle attack. But if there is a proxy in the middle of the way, can the proxy see the Auth data that I pass in the header?

Comment: *If* the proxy is configured to perform SSL termination

Answer (score 0):

Yes, proxy will see the entire request even if it is on HTTPS
Things it will see

- HTTP Method
- URL Requested
- HTTP Method
- ALL HTTP Headers
- Query String Parameters
- Form parameters

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it will even see the credentials if they are passing through the request.